# Cloudflare api error zone identifier cannot be found

Tags: cloudflare

Hey so trying to use the API to purge individual links but what do I replace with identifier in this link? https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/:identifier/purge_cache

Anyone know where it is located exactly, cloudflare support is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [CloudFlare API documentation for Purge Cache](https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-purge-individual-files-by-url-and-cache-tags), you can post an array of files in a HTTP DELETE request to that endpoint.

Now, that identifier is the Zone ID, for this, you can get a list using a GET request on the Zones endpoint, e.g.:

```
$ curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones?name=example.com&status=active&page=1&per_page=20&order=status&direction=desc&match=all" \
-H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
-H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

The ID will be in the "result" variable that comes back. Details are here:  [List zones](https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-list-zones).

After you've got this ID you can then pass it through as the identifier in the DELETE request.

Example with cURL:

```
$ curl -X DELETE "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/purge_cache" \
-H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
-H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"files":["http://www.example.com/css/styles.css"],"tags":["some-tag","another-tag"]}'
```

Response:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "errors": [],
  "messages": [],
  "result": {
    "id": "023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353"
  }
}
```

Comment: Here what I got "Sorry, you have been blocked" This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data.

Answer (score 0):

mjsa is right, but you are probably running into CloudFlare's firewall.

I ran into the exact same problem with CloudFlare blocking my cURL requests. I managed to solve, or rather bypass it, by adding a User-Agent header to my requests. For example:

```
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.87 Safari/537.36"
```